# How to inject Jenkins environmental variables into pom.xml

Tags: docker, jenkins, jira, pom.xml

I'm developing plugin for Atlassian Jira and trying to get the version number of my plugin to be equal Jenkins BUILD_NUMBER environment variable.

Plugin is built inside docker container using command:

docker run --rm --volume $PWD/src/jira_plugin/:/opt/atlas/ codeclou/docker-atlassian-sdk:latest  atlas-package

POM.xml:

```
<project>

<version>${jenkins.buildNumber}</version>

...

    <properties>
        <jenkins.buildNumber>${env.BUILD_NUMBER}</jenkins.buildNumber> 
    </properties>

</project>
```

Result:

> [INFO] Building jar: /opt/atlas/target/test-null.jar ..[ERROR] Failed
>   to execute goal
>   com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-jira-plugin:6.3.15:generate-obr-artifact
>   (default-generate-obr-artifact) on project test: Source
>   '/opt/atlas/target/test${env.BUILD_NUMBER}.jar' does not exist

Nevertheless command

```
 echo `printenv`
```

in docker correctly displays BUILD_NUMBER var.

Question:

What should I add in pom.xml to inject BUILD_NUMBER var in pom.xml  and to display version correctly?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out:

docker run -e BUILD_NUMBER="${BUILD_NUMBER}" ...

So the variable will be injected and can be used in pom.xml.